# Should I start a new thread to get HTTP response on my server?

Tags: java, multithreading, glassfish

I have a Glassfish server and I expect it to be rather loaded. For example, I have RESTful services and I want to make a request to Google API in the one of the methods. Should I create a new Thread to do such a work?

Comment: How exactly will creating a new thread change the work to be done? Or reduce the load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you should avoid managing anything with threads manually inside the Java EE world. This work is should be provided by the container (Glassfish in this case), especially for a HTTP response.

Inside of EJBs it is even prohibited:

> The enterprise bean must not attempt to manage threads. The enterprise
>   bean must not attempt to start, stop, suspend, or resume a thread, or
>   to change a thread’s priority or name. The enterprise bean must not
>   attempt to manage thread groups.

(EJB 3.1 spec, page 599)

There are some exceptions where you may need to do something manually in a web application, but in general it should be avoided.

**See also:**

- [Thread creation in JavaEE EJB/Web containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161634/thread-creation-in-javaee-ejb-web-containers)
- [Java EE specification and multi threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3212255/java-ee-specification-and-multi-threading)